# Centroid and Center of Gravity

Tags: statics, centre-of-gravity

[image: problem on centroid]

I was studying this example but I didn't understand how the author arrived at **(A₁ - A₂)G₁G**

Please I need enlightenment

Comment: you need to show your work. then we can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of finding centroid of an area is $$\bar{x} = \sum\left(\frac{A_i \times d_i}{\sum A_i}\right)$$, "i" is the numerical label of part of an area that makes up the entire area, in here $A_1 = 6 \times 8 =48$ (ideally it should be $A$, or $A_0$, but let's stick to the givens). And "d" is the distance of the centroid of the ith partial area measured to the centroid of the centroid of the entire area, that is marked as "$G_1$" here.

Now let's identify the partial areas of interest, and its distance to the centroid. As indicated, $A_2 = 3$, and $d_2 = -x$ (negative because it is to the left of the centroid axis); and let's call $A_3 = A_1 - A_2 = 48 - 3 = 45$, and $d_3 = 1$. So,

$\sum A_i = A_2 + A_3 = 3 + 45  = 48 $

$\sum(A_i \times d_i) = 3 \times (-x) + 45 \times 1 = -3x + 45 $

To maintain equilibrium of the remaining area, $\sum(A_i \times d_i)$ must equal to $A_1 \times d_1$ (sum of the parts must equal to the whole). $D_1$ is the distance of the centroid of the entire/original area measured to its centroid, $G_1$, thus $d_1 = 0$, so

$\sum(A_i \times d_i) = -3x + 45 = A_1 \times d_1 = 0 $

now solve for x, $x = \frac{45}{3} =$ +15 mm (the positive solution indicates the original assumption $d_2 = -x$ is correct, the area stays to the left of the original centroid, $G_1$).

The problem is testing your understanding on "the first moment of area method", which is described as,

"The first moment of area of a shape, about a certain axis, equals the sum over all the infinitesimal parts of the shape of the area of that part times its distance from the axis [Σ ( a × d )]. First moment of area is commonly used to determine the centroid of an area."

As indicated above, it is most useful in finding the centroid of an irregular shape/area, by summing the area of the parts, and summing the area-moments (A x d) about a reference axis, then the distance of the centroid is obtained through dividing the sum of area-moments by the sum of the areas. Finally, you shall keep one important concept in mind, the area moment of an area/shape about its centroid axis is always zero.

Sorry for the lengthy write up. Hope you got the idea without trouble.